# GraphComparator Java Object Comparison dot notation

Tags: java, object

I am using com.ceadarsoftware.url.GraphComparator to diff two java objects. It seems to be working fine but using Delta.fieldName I'm not able to tell exactly where in the object tree the difference is. In a live use case the object tree would be much larger with several address objects used in different locations.

```
Deal d1 = new Deal();
Address address1 = new Address();
address1.setContactName("Mike");
address1.setCity("Chicago");
d1.setVendorAddress(address1);

Deal d2 = new Deal();
Address address2 = new Address();
address2.setContactName("Mike");
address2.setCity("Providence");
d2.setVendorAddress(address2);

List<GraphComparator.Delta> deltas = GraphComparator.compare(d1, d2, new GraphComparator.ID() {
  @Override
  public Object getId(Object o) {
    return "id";
  }
});

System.out.println(deltas.size()+" diff(s) found:");
for (GraphComparator.Delta d: deltas) {
  System.out.println(d.getFieldName()); //city
}
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to see a dot notation of this? (ex. vendorAddress.city)? I tried Javers but it is a bit too heavy for my needs (too many dependencies for this particular project)

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your problem is. Is the given code producing errors of some kind? If so, what are they? If it's just not working like you want, be more specific about what you expect it to produce and what you are getting instead. It may be necessary to provide more code regarding the classes in question. Personally I'm not familiar with the specific framework in question.

Comment: No errors in code above just limited output. It could be a limitation of this particular library. I am hoping someone with experience with it might have an example. My google code generation searches have come up empty thus far. :)

Comment: Have you been able to find a sollution?
I'm struggling with the same problem...